# How to get the download file name of apt-get download?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I have no sudo privilege, So, I want to install software into my home directory.
I have a lot of package to download, so I want to write a script to do this. I use:

```
apt-get download libopencv-dev
dpkg-deb -x libopencv-dev_2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb /my/path
```

but when I write a script, I don't know the downloaded file name (`libopencv-dev_2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb`), anyone know how the get the file name of `apt-get download`?

Comment: I am not sure that it is even possible to install all packages without privileges but it would be a very serious security risk if you were able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try parsing the output of `apt-get download --print-uris`, which just prints information about the download without actually downloading it:

```
$ apt-get download vim --print-uris
'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.4.1907-1~ppa1~x_amd64.deb' vim_2%3a7.4.1907-1~ppa1~x_amd64.deb 1073208 SHA256:f2d9029ec937fa0d4f16612f21bc2cb4ff2ef8dc16f7f31af660c5cb272d92bc
```

It gives you the URL, the filename, the expected size, and the hash. If you so chose, you could perform the downloading and verification yourself as well (in which case you can download and save to whatever filename you want).

For now:

```
filename=$(apt-get download libopencv-dev --print-uris | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script named `downloadthis`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(apt-cache show $1 | grep Version | sed 's/^Version..//g')
 do apt-get download $1
 dpkg-deb -x "$1"*"$i"*deb $2
 done
```

Don't forget to make it executable.

Here is an example of use:

```
./downloadthis libopencv-dev
```

The script will create a directory named `libopencv-dev` in your home directory. You can edit the script and change `~/$1` to another path (like `/my/path` for example).

Alternatively, you could edit the script and change `~/$1` to `~/$2` to allow you to specify the extract directory when you run the script.

Here is an example of this use:

```
./downloadthis libopencv-dev /my/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the script:

```
PACKAGE=packagename
apt-get download $PACKAGE
dpkg-deb -x $PACKAGE*.deb /my/path
```

This should work for all packages. It may or may not work in PPA's or external repositories.